# Синхронизация данных между SQLite и PostgreSQL

Tags: java, c, база-данных, postgresql, sqlite

Возникла потребность синхронизации данных с `sqlite` в `postgresql`. Коротко говоря все происходит так: `sqlite` (embeded система) собирает данные и при возможности подключения сети начинает сбрасывать все на сервер, сама база данных представляет собой 4 таблицы с связью 1 к многим. `postgresql` работает на удаленном сервере, который принимает и обрабатывает информацию. Таблицы в базах очень похожи за исключением того что на сервере еще должна храниться `id` устройства. Как синхронизировать данные в них?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Воспользоваться чем-то готовым типо такого: https://github.com/sqlite-sync/SQLite-sync.com
2. Делать самим.

   1. Если у вас только вставки и нет апдейтов. В SQLite базе в строках добавить столбец, показывающий, была ли строка отправлена. Периодически отправлять строки, которые имеют статус `false` в этом столбце. После удачной отправки и ответа от сервака ставить флаг в `true`.
   2. Если у вас используются операции `update`, то, по-хорошему, нужно в отдельное место писать дельты изменений и уже их на сервак последовательно отправлять.

Comment: Думаю чем то готовым не выйдет,  стложность в том что sqlite я проектировал и реализовал на встроеной системе на чистом С, нужно все в ручную. Второй пункт нужно обдумать, update-тов кстати нет, все в одностороннем порядке.

Comment: @UjinUkr тогда можно просто строки посылать, но на серваке, вероятно, делать не просто `insert`, а `upsert`.

Comment: eсли писать синхронизацию в ручную то хотелось бы узнать какие тыблицы должны первыми синхронизированы?Первыми должны быть те от которых зависят все остальные?

Comment: @UjinUkr если у вас там целостность внешними ключами настроена, то в первую очередь нужно писать строки из таблиц, на которые ссылаются другие таблицы.

Comment: буду пробовать, спасибо.